# ArcGIS - Editor toolbar not opening

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, arcgis-10.5

I have installed ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 on a new computer and have a problem that I have never experienced with any previous versions of ArcMap.

Pressing the button of the toolbar for the Editor I can’t access the toolbar. Neither does it open if I go to Customize - Toolbars and cross in the box for it there. All other Toolbars seem to open correctly.

I also can see that the program notices that I have pressed the button by the ArcMap-window ‘flickering’ and I see the Editor-toolbar that should open for less than a second at some occasions.

I have tried to see if it ends up hidden somewhere, but it does not seems like it.

[image: Printscreen of the ArcMap window with the editor button]

Does anyone know what can be the problem and how to handle it?

I have tried to search for answers both at the ESRI help-page, here in previous asked questions and in other broad search engines, but this doesn’t seem to be a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend deleting the mxd defaults located here named "normal.mxt":

C:\Users\(user
name)\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop(version#)\ArcMap\Templates

You may have to configure windows to show hidden folders:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files

This will reset the interface to installation defaults next time you start ArcMap.

Comment: This is also useful in case you don't have Admin privileges https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-2121-resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile

Answer (score 0):

Search for this file name "normal.mxt" your computer file explorer search bar  folder and rename it to "normal.old". Take care to close the ArcMap and ArcCatalog before doing this step or renaming and then reopen it again, and it will work.